# Trade Mark symbol not working in MySQL Select Query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

The following query in MySQL as well as Codeigniter gives me an error.

```
SELECT * FROM table where name='hellome� test'
```

Error:

```
#1267 - Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) 
        and (utf8mb4_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='
```

This error also comes in Codeigniter.

**Question**

How to allow this type of characters in MySQL query.

Comment: this is for the United States?

Comment: No, its my requirement

Answer (score 0):

You should set the database character encoding, inside the config > database.php as bellow. "utf8" is your db character encoding.

```
    $db ['default'] = array (
            'dsn' => '',
            'hostname' => 'localhost',
            'username' => '',
            'password' => '',
            'database' => '',
            'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
            'dbprefix' => '',
            'pconnect' => FALSE,
            'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
            'cache_on' => FALSE,
            'cachedir' => '',
            'char_set' => 'utf8',
            'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
            'swap_pre' => '',
            'encrypt' => FALSE,
            'compress' => FALSE,
            'stricton' => FALSE,
            'failover' => array (),
            'save_queries' => TRUE 
    );
```

Comment: This is default settings of codeigniter. Its already in my config file

Answer (score 0):

use active records.

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('blogs');
$this->db->where('name','hellome� test');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely as your table and database schema are in latin. Try running these commands:

- `ALTER DATABASE db CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci`
- `ALTER TABLE table CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci`